# abstract class using its own abstract method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I recently start to read about Abstract class. Most of the site I visited and I see that parent class is abstract and child class define that abstract method of parent class. Its fine for me , but recently I saw a different way of using an abstract class. The code is working , but I couldn't understand the logic. The code is like below

```
    abstract class TestParent
    {
      abstract void display();

       public void accessdisplay()
       {
         display();
       }
    }    //  TestParent

    public class TestChild extends TestParent
    {
       void display()
       {
          System.out.println("child define display");
       }

       void print()
       {
          System.out.println("This is print");
       }

       public static void main(String... arg)
       {
          TestChild t_child=new TestChild();

          t_child.accessdisplay();  
          t_child.print();
          System.out.println("\n******************************************\n");

          TestParent t_parent= new TestChild();

          t_parent.accessdisplay();  
          t_parent.display();  
          //t_parent.print();
       }    
    }
```

the code  is working....but i never see an abstract class try to use its own abstract method....

how the code "t_parent.accessdisplay()" works? i know TestChild is referenced to the TestParent .... so TestChild can access the parent class method....but display() is a abstract method..it define in the child class...how can an object "t_parent" which is reference to parent class can access the method is defined in child class

or there is anything i want to know about abstract class....where is iam missing

pls help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37355445/1260204

Comment: `abstract void display();` <= this declaration can be seen as a promise that any derived concrete classes must implement this method. As an abstract class cannot be instantiated it will never be possible to call the abstract method, only an override of it.

Comment: `t_parent` is declared to be a `TestParent` but it is actually holding a `TestChild` (which is also a `TestParent`) - there is no *pure* **instance** of `TestParent` (will never be since it is abstract)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the OO concept called **Polymorphism**.

"t_chiled" and "t_parent" are object reference variables. **They are not objects themselves.** Think of Them as remote controls(tv remotes). Each method maps in to a button in the remote. And as the child classes inherit methods from parent classes, child object can response to all the buttons from a parent remote control. **Therefore child object can be substituted in place where a parent object is needed.**

Here in this code,

```
TestParent t_parent= new TestChild();
```

Parent object reference variable(t_parent) is referencing to a TestChild object which is created on the heap. It does not refer a TestParent object. Therefore it is not referring the abstract method when

```
t_parent.accessdisplay();
```

this happens. It just refer the overridden method inside the TestChild object.

For more info on polymorphism in java, visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm